# What am I? Riddle

Tags: feature-request, title

So this is the title for a lot of riddles-

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=What+am+I%3F+Riddle

And, you have no idea what you're getting into when you read that title.

So we need a filter that says- don't make your title so unspecific! Change your title.

Comment: Can you describe the question a bit more, explaining the problems you/we face due to this and can you suggest a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

#### Related

[Titling Overhaul](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/titling-overhaul/1439#1439)

#### Problem

I think that titles need to be explicit : When I look at the front page I want to know if I have already seen a puzzle and what it is just by reading the title. Therefor puzzle called "What am I ?" or "An easy Riddle" have really bad title.

#### Solution

I see no problem in manually editing the title to add a piece of the riddle in it. Most of the times (every time?) this kind of title is not an hint or a part of the puzzle.
The difficulty is to choose what part of the riddle we whould add :

- The lines starting with "I am ..." or something similar are very good because you can call the puzzle "I am... What am I ?"
- You can also choose an epic line
- You can simply choose the first line of the riddle (as suggested in the related post)

If the question asker is unhappy with your title he can always roll back to the original boring title or edit it by himself.