# Should we edit "Who/What am I" questions?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, title

Many questions asked on PSE contain "Who am I" or "What am I" in their titles. Most of the time, it also contains something else, to avoid duplicated titles. But I was wondering if we could replace it to have, for example, one line of the riddle in the title instead.

So, **should we edit such questions?**

---

[This answer](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5041/25957) is related to what I am talking about. Here, I am discussing the fact of editing, not the fact of proposing a better title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you should. Titles should be descriptive - something like "Who Am I Riddle" tells you almost nothing about the actual content of the puzzle.